# How to pass querystring to AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, http

I have an URL: website.test/?module=support&item=callScreen&id=10

I also have an AJAX call in my javascript based on back-end parsed variables:

```
if ('{/literal}{$currentDate}{literal}' < '{/literal}{$ticket.lock_date} {literal}') {
    $('#status').attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php'
    });
}
```

The ticketAutoclose.php file:

```
<?php
require_once('../../config.php');

$login = new Login();
if (!$login->checkLogin()) {
    echo lang($_SESSION['language'], "INSUFFICIENT_RIGHTS");
    exit();
}

$db = new Database();

$query = "
    UPDATE 
        tickets 
    SET 
        ticket_status = 8,
        closed_at = NOW()
    WHERE 
        id = :ticket
    ";

$binds = array(
    ':ticket' => $_GET['id']
);
$db->update($query, $binds);
```

When I check my DB, the value has not been edited. So I head to my network interface and detected that the AJAX call threw an error: "undefined index: id". My question thus is: **How can I hand my ticketAutoclose.php file the id that is inside the URL of my current page? (queryString does not seems to work as it currently cannot identify the $_GET['id'], which should be 10.**

Comment: `url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php'` need to be `url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php?id=pass id value here'`

Comment: You can pass url:"/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php?id="+id

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Thanks for that, works!

Comment: or you can set the `data` option in the ajax call. If it's a GET, jQuery will serialise it and append it to the querystring, since there's no request body in a GET

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing id in your request.

1 . append your id in the javascript ajax call like this:

```
     if ('{/literal}{$currentDate}{literal}' < '{/literal}{$ticket.lock_date} {literal}') {
      $('#status').attr("disabled", true);
      var id = $(this).attr('id'); // use your own lagic to fetch the id
      $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php?id=' + id // HERE
      });
    }
```

2 . Do not forget to use `isset()` in your php code

```
<?php
 require_once('../../config.php');

 $login = new Login();
 if (!$login->checkLogin()) {
   echo lang($_SESSION['language'], "INSUFFICIENT_RIGHTS");
   exit();
 }

 if(!isset($_GET['id']))
   exit('please provide ID'); // like this

 $db = new Database();

 $query = "
  UPDATE 
    tickets 
  SET 
    ticket_status = 8,
    closed_at = NOW()
  WHERE 
    id = :ticket
  ";

$binds = array(
':ticket' => $_GET['id']
);
$db->update($query, $binds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself using the smarty templating engine that I also use. There gets an ID send and placed in the URL, so, why not extract that same data and use it in my ajax call? I tried that logic, and it worked. Database records have all been updated by using this:

```
url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php?id='+'{/literal}{$ticket.id}{literal}'
```